# supplying filter value as variable in powershell yields different results

Tags: powershell, scope

I'm trying to do bulk operations on a set of mailboxes on my Exchange 2010 server. To limit the number boxes I need to operate on, I want to filter the results. I know the ones I need to work on are created after 2015-01-01, so I am supplying this as a filter value (which works):

```
$boxes = Get-Mailbox -filter { whenCreated -gt '2015-01-01' }
```

I want to be able to reuse my script later at some point, so I tried to set this up to take a parameter, but its returning all the boxes (does not work)...

```
$filterdate = '2015-01-01'; $boxes = Get-Mailbox -filter { whenCreated -gt $filterdate }
```

My guess is that -Filter is doing some sort of implicit type conversion when I supply a string literal vs when I supply a string variable

How can I supply -Filter with a variable?

edit:

this also returns an unfiltered list:

```
$filterdate = [System.DateTime]'2015-01-01'; get-mailbox -filter { whencreated -gt $filterdate }
```

results in error:

```
$filterdate = '2015-01-01'; get-mailbox -filter { whencreated -gt "$filterdate" }
```

Comment: Try making the value an actual date: `$filterdate = Get-Date '2015-01-01'`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers get-date yields the same result

Comment: Try expanding the string? `{ whenCreated -gt "$filterdate" }`

Comment: Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "The value "$filterdate" could 
not be converted to type System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]."

Comment: Is it not because of the script block? The variable has no value in that scope. Use a quoted string and remove the brackets. `-filter  "whencreated -gt '$filterdate'"`

Comment: @Matt that did the job, thanks! Please post as an answer, and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the issue was the the variable `$filterdate` did not exist in the scope of the scriptblock you made `{ whencreated -gt "$filterdate" }`. The syntax is fine.... until you add variables to the mix. Pretty sure, inside that scope, `$filterdate` would have been null. Then you were getting all the mailboxes because anything is greater than null (accept itself of course).

```
1 -gt $null
"asdf" -gt $null
True
```

Using a properly quoted string you can get the same result.

`-filter "whencreated -gt '$filterdate'"`